# Fastlane and shell script. Was 18 instead of 0

Tags: jenkins, sh, fastlane

I am trying to curl the `.ipa` with `jenkins` using `fastlane` but my script is failing with :

```
'chmod +x ./publish.sh; ./publish.sh;' was 18 instead of 0. (FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneShellError)
Uploading: ./../MobileApp.ipa
```

in my `Fastfile` :

`sh('chmod +x ./publish.sh; ./publish.sh;')`

Here is the content of my script :

```
#!/bin/bash -e

upload() {
  for file in ./../*.ipa; do
    echo "Uploading: $file"
  response=$(
    curl -u $PUBLISH_USER:$PUBLISH_PASS -T $file http://example.com/ios-dev-local/ \
        --write-out %{http_code} \
        --silent \
        --output /dev/null \
  )
  done
}

upload;

if [ "$response" -gt 400 ];
then
  echo "bounce with status $response"
  exit 1;
fi;
```

And here is the full stacktrace:

```
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/ui.rb:14:in `method_missing'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/helper/sh_helper.rb:75:in `sh_control_output'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/helper/sh_helper.rb:16:in `sh_no_action'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:184:in `block in sh'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:50:in `execute_action'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:183:in `sh'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:178:in `sh'
from Fastfile:68:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in `block in execute'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `execute'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:56:in `cruise_lane'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:34:in `handle'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in run'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.5/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.5/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in `call'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.5/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in `run'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.5/lib/commander/runner.rb:476:in `run_active_command'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:66:in `run!'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.5/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:343:in `run'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:42:in `start'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:75:in `take_off'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/fastlane-2.69.2/bin/fastlane:20:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/bin/fastlane:22:in `load'
from /Users/myUser/.fastlane/bin/bundle/bin/fastlane:22:in `<main>'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Can someone explain to me what is that 18 error code I received and why it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the return value of something in that command line. I assume you've tried executing exactly that by hand with no problem. Usually when there's a failure from a shell command, you get the shell output as well before that error. Does it say anything about why it's failing? Have you tried `chmod +x ./publish.sh && ./publish.sh` to make sure it doesn't try to execute the script unless `chmod` succeeds?

If none of that helps, I would recommend trying something like this to investigate further:

```
sh "chmod", "+x", "./publish.sh" do |status, output, command|
  unless status.success?
    UI.user_error! "#{command} failed with status #{status.exitstatus}. Output was #{output}"
  end

  sh "./publish.sh" do |status, output, command|
    unless status.success?
      UI.user_error! "#{command} failed with status #{status.exitstatus}. Output was #{output}"
    end
  end
end
```

This is just to help you see what's failing and how `sh` error handling works. I think the output of the command should show you the error. And you may already have it without these changes.

Also, more on `sh` here: https://docs.fastlane.tools/advanced/#using-the-sh-method

**Updated**

I suspect `curl` is returning 18. From the `curl` man page:

```
18     Partial file. Only a part of the file was transferred.
```

And you're not seeing that in the output of curl because your shell script is swallowing the output. You may need to modify your script in the loop to do something like:

```
if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then echo $response; fi
```